# I'm getting a 404 error when I try to deploy my node.js backend. CORS origin error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, cors, backend

Here is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const FormMain = require('./Routes/FormMain');
const connectDB = require('./Middleware/mongoose');
const helmet = require("helmet");
connectDB();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors(
    {
        origin: "https://manojvfullstackexample.in",
        methods: ["POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE"],
        credentials: true
    }
));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json("Hello");
})
app.use('/api/details',verifyAPI, FormMain);
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`)
})
```

I have tried many answers but all of them ask me to use the vercel.json file. But even with the file I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue on my own. The problem was I had not declared the allowed origin as a string of array and instead used it as a string in my index.js file.

Here is my previous code:

```
app.use(cors(
    {
        origin:"I had entered allowed origin link like this"
    }
));
```

I changed the above to:

```
app.use(cors(
    {
        origin:["I entered the allowed origin here"]
    }
));
```

Javascript not having a type surely makes it easy to program but a nightmare to debug.